# Execute a while loop for each element in an array

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I'm using the library **moment js**.
I'm trying to push into an array called *result* for example each monday, tuesday and wednseday between a start and an end date, but when I try to push all these days into the same array I only get the first position that I have in the array, in this case only the mondays.

I suspect that the logic problem it's between the "***" in the code below

**How can I push the days into the same array?**

Thanks in advance

---

1 = monday

2 = tuesday

...

7 = sunday

---

```
var start:Moment = moment(); // today
var end:Moment   = moment('2022-09-02');

days:number[]   = [1, 2, 3];  // monday, tuesday, wednesday 

function getDates(start:Moment, end:Moment, days:number[]) {
    // year, month, day
    
    let result:Moment[] = [];
    let current:Moment = start.clone();
    
    
    ***
    days.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element);
        while (current.day(7 + element).isBefore(end)) {
            result.push(current.clone());
        }
    });
    ***
    
    
    
    result.map(m => m.format('YYYY/MM/DD'))
    
    // result var with dates formatted to string
    let datesResult:string[] = result.map(m => m.format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
    console.log(datesResult);
}

getDates(start, end, days);
```

> output

```
['2022/08/15', '2022/08/22', '2022/08/29']
```

Comment: I would think you'd want 7 to become 14, then 21, etc.

Comment: That's correct,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not updating current inside of your while loop. You want:

```
while (current.day(7 + element).isBefore(end)) {
    result.push(current.clone());
    current = current.add(1, 'days');
}
```

Comment: I have a doubt: what means 'days' in these code?
I'm still getting the same output

Comment: Edited answer to set current = ... so current actually gets changed. The add function here returns a moment equal to current plus 1.

Comment: I'm still getting the same output